# Google App Engine Gradle Dependency Conflict

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-gradle-plugin, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm facing a problem with my dependencies in my app that will not let me add my `endpoints-backend` module as a dependency to my `app` module like so:

[image: dependencies]

When I compile, it gives me this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'. >com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 3

When I remove the `endpoints-backend` dependency, the program runs, but I need it as a dependency so I can access the endpoints code inside my MainActivity.

Here's my Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.blume.android"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile project(path: ':endpoints-backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
compile project(path: ':cloud-backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
compile 'javax.persistence:persistence-api:1.0'
compile project(':endpoints-backend')
}
```

All Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should remove this line:

```
compile project(':endpoints-backend')
```

You have it included here:

```
compile project(path: ':endpoints-backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
```

Comment: The only problem is when I do so, I can no longer access the endpoints module inside of my MainActivity.